# Last update broke transparencies

Tags: 16.04, kde, plasma, compositing

I have Kubuntu 16.04 on a Thinkpad T450s with no dedicated GPU.
I always used XRender.

After the last update, compositing does not seem to work anymore: in particular, the Konsole background is not transparent even if it should be.

(It seems that all the windows that are supposed to trigger the "blur" effect are not working...)

Any solutions? Anybody had the same problem?

I can't switch to OpenGL, because that way somehow Yakuake doesn't work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Also, on Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: I have the same problem, KDE Neon

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem today after an update. I have an Lenovo G50-70  (i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz), also without a dedicated GPU.

The only thing I did was change OpenGL2 to XRender and I now I'm able to use Yakuake propertly (also, some Firefox menus were broken and now work.)

Please go to <kbd>SystemSettings</kbd>→<kbd>Display and Monitor</kbd>→<kbd>Compositor</kbd>→<kbd>Rendering backend</kbd>.

You may find these in the configuration file: `~/.config/kwinrc`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1054601/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Well, yes, I can use xrender, but transparency there doesn't work either...

Comment: @geodude: Weird, in my setup transparency works well with XRender, but not blur.

Comment: Thank you for this! I wondered why suddenly yakuake no longer worked after a reboot.